# Outside of aesthetics, is there any reason for variance between the two anatomy posters?

Tags: two-point-hospital

There are two posters for the training room—"anatomy poster" and "brain anatomy poster"—both with the same attributes, most importantly "+1% training speed". [The bonus stacks](https://www.reddit.com/r/TwoPointHospital/comments/9cpusk/my_cheap_training_room_p/). Because unlocking costs 80 kudos do I even need the other one?

[image: dozens of anatomy posters in a room]

Comment: That screenshot is impressive but devoid of skeletons. Every hospital needs skeletons.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for unlocking both, it's pure aesthetics.

By the way, if you are looking to optimize your training room, the encyclopedia bookshelf II offered by getting 2 stars in Mitton University gives you 4% per item, so you can get even more effective training using those instead of posters.